# curl with ssh -R proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, curl

I'm on Windows A and I have a Linux server B.

I have a proxy (Clash) on A, `curl -x localhost:7890 www.google.com` works well.

I want to let B `curl www.google.com` through the proxy on A. Here is my method:

```
# on A
ssh -N -R 6666:localhost:7890 root@hostB
```

```
# on B
curl -x localhost:6666 www.google.com
```

The above command fails with:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Why is it that the proxy only allows `localhost` (A) to connect?

Comment: Probably you configured the proxy (or it is configured by default) so that it only listens on loopback interface. You must change the configuration to listen on all interfaces.